# ANR handling, show messagebox

Tags: android

Is it possible for a class to listen to events which is triggered when ANR? My goal is to show the user a custom dialog, where the `stacktrace` is displayed with a button that allows the user to post the stacktrace to support. Do not care about the dialog, I can do this myself, I'm just interested in ANR handling(libraries or eventhandling)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. ANR event is triggered when the UI thread hangs on some long running operation. All ui related operations are dispatched in this thread, so you can not just display a custom `Dialog` becuase the thread is blocked.

I'm not sure if you really need such `Dialog` because `Android` already has a similiar one that allows users to send ANR reports to `Google Play Developer console`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My application is not going to be published to Google Play.